# Reference SharePoint inside a .Net core2.1 project

Tags: sharepoint-server, .net, mvc

I have a solution that is targeting .Net Core2.1 Framework. Now inside I want to be able to query sharepoint list items. But I see I can't add Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in the project. I tried changing the targeted framework under project properties but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me understand if it's possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you are married to .NET Core your only real option is the REST APIs, and you are going to have to wire up all the code infrastructure and authentication yourself.

So, not impossible, but a bit lower level.